# jquery, сделать корректно autofocus для input

Tags: jquery

Я пытаюсь сделать autofucus, когда пользователь попадает на шаг 2, чтобы автоматически был автофокус на поле и мог сразу же писать в этом поле текст (не кликая на input)
но это не работает, мне серавно приходиться кликать на input, чтобы начать писать текст

```
    if(n === 2){
        console.log('1q');
        jQuery('#tell-more-textarea').attr('autofocus','autofocus');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно прямо задать состояние фокуса для поля:

```js
var currentStep = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
  currentStep++;
  $('.step-form__step').hide().eq(currentStep).show().find('input,select,textarea').eq(0).focus();
})
```

```css
input,select,textarea{
  display:block;
  margin:0 0 10px;
}
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
.step-form__step:nth-child(n+2){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step-form">
  <div class="step-form__body">
    <div class="step-form__step">
      <p>olololo azazaaza    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="step-form__step">
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type="text" placeholder="ololo">
    </div>
    <div class="step-form__step">
      <select>
        <option>нет</option>
        <option>нет</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" placeholder="ololo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Туда →</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!